# Save files in designated folders

Tags: vba, ms-word

This is code derived from [Mail Merge Tips and Tricks](https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html).

```
Sub Merge_To_Individual_Files()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim StrFolder As String, StrName As String, MainDoc As Document, i As Long, j As Long
Set MainDoc = ActiveDocument
With MainDoc
  StrFolder = .Path & Application.PathSeparator
  For i = 1 To .MailMerge.DataSource.RecordCount
    With .MailMerge
      .Destination = wdSendToNewDocument
      .SuppressBlankLines = True
      With .DataSource
        .FirstRecord = i
        .LastRecord = i
        .ActiveRecord = i
        If Trim(.DataFields("Name")) = "" Then Exit For
        StrName = .DataFields("Number") & "_" & .DataFields("Name") & "_Test"
      End With
      .Execute Pause:=False
    End With
    StrName = Trim(StrName)
    With ActiveDocument
      .SaveAs2 FileName:=StrFolder & StrName & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
      .PrintOut Copies:=1
      .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
  Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code separates a serial letter into individual files, saves them as pdf and starts the printing.

The macro saves all the files in the same folder and I have to move each file to the designated folder manually (each file has an own folder with the "Number" from the code as its name).

Is it possible to save the files directly in the intended folder?

Comment: Is `StrPath` set somewhere?  Did you mean `StrFolder`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```vb
Dim num, numGen as long, f, StrFolder As String
'...
'...
num = .DataFields("Number") 'capture the value in the With .DataSource block
'...
'...

'check if the destination folder exists
f = FindFolder(StrFolder, CStr(num)) 'returns folder path if exists

If Len(f) = 0 Then
    'no match was found - use a generic folder
    f =   StrFolder & "General" 'or whatever you want
    numGen = numGen + 1
End If

.SaveAs2 FileName:= f & _
         Application.PathSeparator & StrName & ".pdf", _
         FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF, AddToRecentFiles:=False
'...
'...
'Notify that some files need to be moved
If numGen > 0 Then
    Msgbox numGen & " files were saved to 'General' folder"
End If
```

This function will return the path of any matched folder given a starting folder to begin in (includes searching in subfolders).  Returns empty string if no match.

```vb
Function FindFolder(StartAt As String, ByVal folderName As String) As String
    Dim colFolders As New Collection, sf, path, fld, fso
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colFolders.Add StartAt
    Do While colFolders.Count > 0
        fld = colFolders(1)
        colFolders.Remove 1
        If Right(fld, 1) <> "\" Then fld = fld & "\"
        For Each sf In fso.getfolder(fld).subfolders
            If sf.Name = folderName Then
                FindFolder = sf.path
                Exit Function
            Else
                colFolders.Add sf
            End If
        Next sf
    Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it and the files were saved in the correct folder. Unfortunately I faced an other problem. The problem concerns the folllowing. If the designated folder of a file doesn't exist yet, the macro stops working. Would it be possible to set a general folder and save all the files, that don't have a designated folder, in this folder? So that the makro saves the file with an existing folder in the designated folder and all the others in the general folder. Thanks in advance and Merry Christmas!

Comment: Would it be better to have the macro create the "number" folder if it doesn't already exist?

Comment: Unfortunately, the folders already exist but without the number (only the name of the person). The number of the folder is getting added later on manually, but sometimes the person in power forgets to do that. So creating new folders would mean that some people have 2 folders.

Comment: Sorry for the late respond, I was quite busy. I could try your code and it works. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I faced another problem. The makro doesn't find the designated folder if it's a subfolder. Is it possible to search the whole folder (with all the subfolders)?

Comment: It works perfect. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is derived from the *Send Mailmerge Output to Individual Files* article in the **Mailmerge Tips & Tricks** thread, at https://www.msofficeforums.com/mail-merge/21803-mailmerge-tips-tricks.html.

That article contains code for setting the save path and tells you how to use it...